# Why toDataURL is so slow?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

If I transfer a simple image through the network, it's fast. When I try to transfer the same image created in a canvas using `toDataURL` it's much slower. Why?

Comment: not enough information.

Comment: Optimization? How much does the regular image weigh compared to the generated one?

Comment: What is "much slower"? Your title says `toDataURL` is slow, but post itself talks about "transfer"... Please measure each part separately and update your post (including size of the data being sent).

Comment: toDataURL takes an optional type parameter, and creates a png by default. Are you sure you are comparing same typed files ?

Answer (score 12):

You are not giving too much context so in general:

When you use `toDataURL()` the browser will encode the image as a Base-64 stream with a small header. The base-64 will always increase the size by 33% compared to non-encoded size.

If you are natively transferring a JPEG encoded file it will typically be smaller in size than a PNG version of the image. If you forget to specify image type for `toDataURL` the browser will always default to PNG.

In this case, specify JPEG this way:

```
var quality = 0.7;
var dataUri = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality);
```

Comment: Follow up question. Are there any disadvantages in saving the dataUri to lets say localstorage, in terms of performance?

Comment: @JohnAndrews not for performance (the overhead would still be there), but data-uri would be required as localSotrage only takes strings. But storage *space* will easily become an issue. IndexedDB is a better choice for this IMHO and it can store Blobs.

Comment: Ahh that was it, I assumed it would default to the input image, changing to jpeg made things way faster thanks dude! Looking forward to Chrome implementing `canvas.toBlob` so it can be even faster and non-blocking