# Need to set content of canvas to image very very fast

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dart

I am developing a game using HTML5 and I have to transfer the content of a canvas into an ImageElement. The following dart code works

```
img.src = _canvas.toDataUrl();
img.width = w;
img.height = w;
```

but is awfully slow, taking ~120 ms every time! The game must maintain 60 fps at all cost and 120 ms for an operation as trivial as this is way too expensive. How else can I do this very quickly?

Note: I am programming in Dart but Javascript translates very well to Dart so I don't mind javascript answers

Thanks

Comment: What are canvas dimensions?

Comment: is 120ms how long it takes to conver  the canvas to a image source? Or is that also including some sort of transfer time?

Also I refer you to this similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557793/why-todataurl-is-so-slow

Comment: Ah, so it converts it to base64. I don't need it in base64 so is it possible to directly set the ImageData of the ImageElement?

Comment: Perhaps you should try the given answer in that link and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: How often do you need to capture the canvas and do you need to use the image immediately? If you just need to occasionally save the canvas contents, then create a few new in-memory canvases and `newContext.drawImage(gameCanvas,0,0)` the game canvas onto the in-memory canvas. This is very fast. Then you can do `.toDataURL` at a convenient time to generate the image data url.

Comment: So the real question is why do you need to transfer it to an ImageElement ?

Answer (score 3):

Just use another canvas element. Unless you have a specific reason to use the image element the two are similar enough to be interchangeable.

```
var img = document.getElementById("cImg");
img.ctx = img.getContext("2d");
img.getImg = function(source,w,h){   // close over img
    img.style.width = w + "px";  // will change resolution 
    img.style.height = h + "px"; 
    img.width = w;   // if you only set these two resolution will remain constant
    img.height = h;  // only the display size will change. If you do you will 
                     // have to copy to the resolution size not the display size.
    img.ctx.drawImage(source, 0, 0, w, h);
};
```

Then once a frame 60fps just call `img.getImg`

```
img.getImg(_canvas, w, h);
```

Very fast (you will barely notice it) and outwardly looks like an image.